# django exclude span multi-value relationships

Tags: django, django-queryset

I read about [spanning multi-valued relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) in the docs and saw the 
example:

```
Blog.objects.exclude(
    entry=Entry.objects.filter(
        headline__contains='Lennon',
        pub_date__year=2008,
    ),
)
```

If I want to add F expressions to this example like:

```
Blog.objects.exclude(
    entry=Entry.objects.filter(
        headline__contains='Lennon',
        pub_date__year=2008,
        test_1=F('test_2')
    ),
)
```

which 'test_2' is a field of Blog, how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well,

```
Blog.objects.exclude(
    entry=Entry.objects.filter(
        headline__contains='Lennon',
        pub_date__year=2008,
        test_1=F('blog__test_2')
    ),
)
```

allows you to reach the test_2 field in the related Blog table (i.e. use two underscores to span relationships)